# Concatenating dataframes in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am struggling with something simple and it drives me crazy.

Why concatenating like below doesn't replace df1 with df1 + additional column??

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3], 'B':[4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3], 'B':[4, 5, 6]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C':[999, 999, 999]})

for table in [df1, df2]:
    table = pd.concat((table, df3), axis=1)
df1
```

[image]

Thanks!

[edit] I need to obtain separatly for df1 and df2:

[image]

Comment: No, I mean I want to separetly add df3 to df1 and df2. and not concat all three together.

Comment: You are storing the result of your `concat` in the variable `table` and then printing `df1`. The variable `df1` won't change. The result of your mergers are stored in `table`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two DataFrames. These variables are referenced by two variable names "df1" and "df2". Now, you loop over these dataFrames in a loop under the alias "table". Inside the loop, "table" is reassigned to the result of `concat`. Since `concat` is not inplace, *none* of the original DataFrames are modified.

My advice is to maintain a list of DataFrames.

```
df_list = [df1, df2]
```

Now, modify the *list*:

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i] = pd.concat([df, df3], axis=1)
```

`df_list` will reflect the update because it will now hold the newly created `concat` outputs.

```
df1, df2 = df_list

print(df1)
   A  B    C
0  1  4  999
1  2  5  999
2  3  6  999

print(df2)
   A  B    C
0  1  4  999
1  2  5  999
2  3  6  999
```

Comment: Now i understand. I falsely thought that even if 'table' is used as alias the result of concat will be assigned to one of the data frames which is alliased in particular loop. I am actually surprised that alias cannot be used as variable assignment, but I am still learning so this is expected :)